# Ignore specific main files when using bower-installer

Tags: javascript, user-interface, bower, yeoman, bower-install

So I'm working on a yeoman generator and using bower-installer to install front-end dependancies.

Problem I am having is slick-carousel lists slick.css, slick.scss and slick.less as main files and I'm only after slick.scss.

So with bower-installer is there a way I can ignore the css and less files?

I've tried adding to the ignore array, with various different file paths but no luck.

Is it possible? and if so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

FYI My bower file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "authors": [
    "Rawnet <development@rawnet.com>"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "jquery"
  ],
  "install": {
    "path": "/ui/app/vendor",
    "ignore": [
      "jquery"
    ]
  },
  "overrides": {
    "slick": {
      "slick-carousel": ["slick.scss", "slick.js"]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "picturefill": "^3.0.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it working with sources, this is my new bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "authors": [
    "Rawnet <development@rawnet.com>"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "jquery"
  ],
  "install": {
    "path": "/ui/app/vendor",
    "ignore": [
      "jquery"
    ],
    "sources": {
      "slick-carousel": ["bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss", "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "picturefill": "^3.0.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ignore` option works differently as it makes other users install your project with bower ignore files. What you want is the `override` option, you may use it like this to override the main property of a certain bower.json file (you might need to adapt the package name and the path to slick.scss)

Edit: This belongs in YOUR bower.json file, where it should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "THE NAME OF YOUR PACKAGE",

  "overrides": {
    "slick": {
      "slick-carousel": ["slick.css"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get this working, can you show me where this would go in my bower file?

Comment: @SimonSturgess the package you used is called "slick-carousel", right? Just edited the bower.json file so it should work for you. You simply need the "overrides"-part in it.

Comment: Sorry, this still isn't working. I've updated my original question with my new bower file.